# What is a good workflow for git-annex?

Tags: git, workflow, git-annex

Our development team has been using git for version control and using git-annex to store large binary files (data-binaries, images, test-binaries etc). Although we have been able to set it up and use it, we have had our set of troubles.

A common action that we frequently perform that has given us trouble is:

1. Developer 1 adds some tests for a new feature and adds corresponding data for the tests using git-annex.

   ```
   git add <test-file>
   git annex add <data-file>
   git annex copy <data-file> --to=<remote location(we use s3 if that is relevant)>
   git commit -m 'Tests with data'
   git push
   git annex sync
   ```
2. The work is reviewed and merged (we use Github for hosting and follow a forking model where all work is done by a developer on their own fork and merged into the main repository through Pull requests)
3. Developer 2 fetches/merges with upstream and tries to run the tests on his machine.

   ```
   git fetch upstream
   git merge upstream/<branch>
   git annex sync
   git annex get
   ```

We often end up with the test data either not being tracked in git or unable to be downloaded from the remote location.

What is a good way to use git-annex in our workflow?

As an aside, what are other options that might make such a workflow better/easier to manage?

Comment: Maybe explain *"We often end up with the test data either not being tracked in git or unable to be downloaded from the remote location."* better.  What causes the problem?  People forgetting to use git-annex? S3 not available? Something else?

Comment: In your use case you probally often dont used git add to track the files and you also dont used git annex sync --content to sync the files it self you only synced meta

Answer (score 2):

Ok Here we go:

Manual git annex v6 use:

Server1 & Server2:

```
mkdir testdata
cd testdata
git init
git annex init "LocationNameIdentifyer"
git annex upgrade
git remote add OtherServerLocationNameIdentifyer ssh://otherserver.com/thedir
```

when this setup is ready and there are no extra files in the directory you can now run

```
git annex sync --content
```

on both location if there are files in both location you need to do

```
git add --all
```

in both locations to track current files as so called unlocked files

after

```
git annex sync --content
```

on both locations runned lets say 3 times

all is merged and you can now cron git annex sync --content in both locations and both have same files in the worktree if you want to track new files you puted in a location you do git add not git annex add git annex add will add the files as so called locked files that makes a totall other workflow

Answer (score 1):

This will let you have a git repo "myrepo" with related S3 bucket that holds all of the big files you don't really want in your git repository.

Set up the repo:

```
# Clone your repo "myrepo"
git clone git@github.com:me/myrepo.git
cd myrepo

# Initialize it to work with git-annex.  
# This creates .git/annex directory in the repo, 
# and a `git-annex` metadata branch the tools use behind the scenes.
git annex init                  

# The first time you use the repo with git-annex someone must link it to S3.
# Be sure to have AWS_* env vars set.
# Select a name that is fitting to be a top-level bucket name.
# This creates the bucket s3://myrepo-annexfiles-SOME_UUID.
git annex initremote myrepo-annexfiles type=S3  

# Save the repo updates related to attaching your git annex remote.
# Warning: this does a commit and push to origin of this branch plus git-annex.
# It will ALSO grab other things so make sure you have committed
# or stashed those to keep them out of the commit.
git annex sync
```

Add some files to the annex:

```
# These examples are small for demo.
mkdir mybigfiles
cd mybigfiles
echo 123 > file1
echo 456 > file2

# This is the alternative to `git add`
# It replaces the files with symlinks into .git/annex/.../SOME_SHA256.
# It also does `git add` on the symlinks, but not the targets.
git annex add file*             

# Look at the symlinks with wonder.
ls -l mybigfiles/file*    

# This puts the content into S3 by SHA256 under the attached to your "special remote":
git annex move file* --to myrepo-annexfiles 

# Again, this will do a lot of committing and pushing so be prepared.
git annex sync
```

With `git-annex` the git repo will just have dead symlinks that contain a SHA256 value for the real file content, and the tooling will bring down the big files.

Later, when someone else clones the repo and wants the files:

```
git clone myrepo
cd myrepo

# Enable access to the S3 annex files.
# NOTE: This will put out a warning about ssh because the origin above is ssh.
# This is ONLY telling you that it can't push the big annex files there.
# In this example we are using git-annex specifically to ensure that.
# It is good that it has configured your origin to NOT participate here.
git annex enableremote myrepo-annexfiles

# Get all of the file content from S3:
git annex get mybigfiles/*
```

When done with the files, get your disk space back:

```
git annex drop mybigfiles/*
```

Check to see where everything really lives, and what is really downloaded where:

```
git annex whereis mybigfiles/file*
```

Note that git-annex is a super flexible tool.  I found that distilling down a simpler recipe for the common case required a bit of study of the docs.  Hope this helps others.